# Navbar color change - how to

Tags: css, laravel, navbar

I'm fairly new to all this. I have a simple question, hopefully i will get an easy answer.

I want to change the bootstrap `navbar` color from blue to white. **PROBLEM**, i do not know where to locate where to edit this? Probably in the .css files, but which one? I see the one of the footer, but not from `navbar`.

I have tried for days now and just can't find it, i have looked in all the files. probably overlooked it.

Please help?

Comment: if you use `<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">` include your own css file after bootstrap.min.css and add `.navbar-default { background-color: green!important; border-color: green!important;}`

Comment: You don't need to change bootstrap css, you can just add new css style in you navbar. you can use inline css to change the color. how to add inline css, search in Google

Comment: Thanks! I temp fixed it with inline css

Answer (score 1):

Add the following class in your CSS.

```
 ul.nav a{color:#fff !important;}
```